# Is it possible to intercept an HTML form post and do some processing before sending it to it's final destination?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to extend the functionality of an ASP.net application that I'm working with. For its logon page, it uses an html form to post to a dll to handle it's login logic.

I'm wondering if there is any way to redirect that html POST to my C# code so that I can do some processing and then (and this is the part that I haven't figured out yet) POST it to the dll so that the regular logon logic can continue.

I can make changes to the logon page, but the final step must be to do an HTML POST to the dll. I can't change that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Create an IHttpModule.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649096.aspx) You can intercept any request in your application and massage it before passing it onto the rest of the application.

Answer (score 1):

If you can modify the login page, then you can change the submit button to run some JavaScript code first. Your JavaScript code can then use XMLHttp to call your C# code on the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can't html post to a dll.  What is the address that the login page post is directed to?  If not specified, it will be the page itself so you can "intercept" all you like in the code behind.

Comment: @John - In a dotnet project, no, I hadn't.  I guess this is the thing I learned today.